# Is there a way to alter all columns in a SQL table to have 'utf-8' format

Tags: sql, apache-spark, utf-8, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark and I found that my data is not being correctly interpreted. I've tried using `decode` and `encode` built-in functions but they can be applied only to one column at a time.

**Update:**

An example of the behaviour I am having:

```
+-----------+
|    Pa�s  |
+-----------+
|  Espa�a  |
+-----------+
```

And the one I'm expecting:

```
+-----------+
|    País   |
+-----------+
|  España   |
+-----------+
```

The sentence is just a simple

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
```

Comment: Hi NachoAG, do you have an example what you exactly want to do?

Comment: Im updating the post with it